# Mysql division result types

Tags: mysql

How can I discover what the resulting type of an arithmetic operation is in MySQL, as I cannot find it referenced in the manual?

If you perform:

```
SELECT table.a/table.b;
```

then how can I find the resulting type of the expression "table.a/table.b" (for a given set of known column types)?

I have searched the documentation, and there's very little type information specified for numerical operators:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_divide

Comment: is there a relatinship between the two tables?

Comment: So in this particular case they're the same table (and the result is then being used in a more complex way). I'm trying to tell what the resultant type is so I can estimate potential floating point errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you have given actually does specify this quite well. To summarise:

- If both values are integers and one is unsigned, then the result will be an unsigned integer.
- If either value is a real, the result will be a real with precision equal to the maximum precision of the two operands.
- If both values are exact values (integer or decimal) then the result will be an exact value with precision of the first (top/numerator) operator plus a number of additional decimal places from the `div_precision_increment` system variable, set to 4 by default.

Comment: Bah - knew it should have been in there somewhere - I really expected it to be under the specific operator.

Presumably that means the result of an INT/INT devision would be of type DECIMAL({SOMETHING}, div_precision_increment)?